# Can Json.NET populate readonly fields in a class?

Tags: .net, json.net

I haven't seen much information about Json.NET supporting deserializing objects with `readonly` fields. I do notice that the .NET DataContract and DataMember attributes allow for populating `readonly` fields during deserializtion, but Json.NET doesn't seem to support this, at least from the behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

afai can see changing a field to `readonly` results in a `null` value after deserialization.  I had a working sample for another question (modified as shown below), and that's the behaviour I see.

```
public class NameAndId
{
    public string name;
    public int id; 
}

public class Data
{
    public NameAndId[] data;
}

public class Target
{
    public string id;
    public readonly NameAndId from;
    public DateTime updated_time;
    public readonly string message;
    public Data likes;
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\json.txt");
        Target newTarget = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Target>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the same behavior I see. Unfortunately, this along with constructor restrictions on the serialized objects is the deal-breaker for Json.NET for me. :(

Comment: My guess is that the .Net builtin classes have privileged access to those fields that are not available to the third-party library.

Comment: It's no different than setting any other field with reflection, so it's doable and I've filed a feature request on the Json.NET issue tracker.

Comment: @MarkLeMoine There are actually - to my knowledge - no ctor restrictions that you can't get around by creating a custom contract resolver.

Answer (score 10):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can extend the DefaultConstractResolver to do it:

```
public class ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.Writable = CanSetMemberValue(member, true);
        return property;
    }

    public static bool CanSetMemberValue(MemberInfo member, bool nonPublic)
    {
        switch (member.MemberType)
        {
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                var fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)member;

                return nonPublic || fieldInfo.IsPublic;
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)member;

                if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite)
                    return false;
                if (nonPublic)
                    return true;
                return (propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(nonPublic) != null);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have just remove one little check from the CanSetMemberValue method. Unfortunately it's neither virtual nor an instance method, so I had to override CreateProperty as well.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done now. Declare your properties using the `JsonProperty` attribute, and ensure that they have a protected set declared:

```
[JsonProperty("Name")] public string Name {get; protected set;}
```

This didn't work for me when using only a `get`, but works perfectly with the `protected set`.

Comment: The `[JsonProperty]` attribute is not required for this to work

Comment: It didn't work for me any other way in 2017. And I tried practically every combination I could come up with. I was writing a code-generator, so I spent quite a lot of time making the generated code as tight as possible. But this certainly may have been changed in the last two years.